# recursively "normalize" filenames

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [recursively “normalize” filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721249/recursively-normalize-filenames)

Q on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=19iYZpwY
i mean getting rid of special chars in filenames, etc.

i have made a script, that can recursively rename files [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kXeHbDQw]:
e.g.: before:

THIS i.s my file (1).txt

after running the script:

This-i-s-my-file-1.txt

Ok. here it is: 

But: when i wanted to test it "fully", with filenames like this [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LQ07ntcS]: 

¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÊËÌÎÏÐÑÒÔÕ×ØÙUÛUÝÞßàâãäåæçèêëìîïðñòôõ÷øùûýþÿ.txt
áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£.txt<br>
<br>
it fails [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iu8Pwrnr]:<br>
$ sh renamer.sh directorythathasthefiles<br>
mv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^*`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^*`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^*`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^*`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directorymv: cannot stat`./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†....and so on
$

so "mv" can't handle special chars.. :\

i worked on it for many hours..

does anyone has a working one? [that can handle chars [filenames] in that 2 lines too?]

Comment: That bash script is terri-bad. Are you open to using Python?

Comment: 12 questions asked and no accepted answer ? Not good...

Comment: Cross-posted to [SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/223514/recursively-normalize-filenames) and [SU](http://superuser.com/questions/234448/recursively-normalize-filenames).

Comment: For future reference, [in this answer on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/234448/recursively-normalize-filenames/234466#234466), grawity posted a link to the [detox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/detox) utility (plus tackled some of the mess in the OP's script). Go upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Reading that script was almost painful...

For one, you should read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Then you should read about [bash functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html). After that you should read about [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and [tr](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html)

Then you should consider this: do you really want to *move* the file each time that you perform a transformation on its name?

Then after all this thinking, you should come up with something a bit saner.

Answer (score 0):

Wtf is going on your system? You should consider re setting up and pay attention on sane applicaitons and security.

However its very likely that you are just running into the max length of command arguments if i am looking at that.

If not, well install UTF8 locales and install them as system default.

On debian based systems this is usually just a matter of `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

also work on your accept rate.