# recursively "normalize" filenames

Tags: linux, bash, sh

i mean getting rid of special chars in filenames, etc.

i have made a script, that can recursively rename files [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kXeHbDQw]:

e.g.: before:

```
THIS i.s my file (1).txt
```

after running the script:

```
This-i-s-my-file-1.txt
```

Ok. here it is:

But: when i wanted to test it "fully", with filenames like this:

```
¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÊËÌÎÏÐÑÒÔÕ×ØÙUÛUÝÞßàâãäåæçèêëìîïðñòôõ÷øùûýþÿ.txt
áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&'()*+,:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£.txt
```

it fails [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iu8Pwrnr]:

```
$ sh renamer.sh directorythathasthefiles
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†....and so on
$
```

so "mv" can't handle special chars.. :\

i worked on it for many hours..

does anyone has a working one? [that can handle chars [filenames] in that 2 lines too?]

Comment: [Accepted answer rate of zero](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) doesn't make your profile look good.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/223514/recursively-normalize-filenames).

Comment: Why migrated from superuser? This is shell scripting, not programming...

Comment: Consider using `tr` instead of `sed`. You save lots of lines with tr.

Comment: @grawity: You just carry believing that... I'll stick to real code.

Comment: @grawity: Note: I said shell scripting.

Answer (score 18):

`mv` handles special characters just fine. Your script doesn't.

---

In no particular order:

1. You are using `find` to find all directories, and `ls` each directory separately.

   1. Why use `for DEPTH in...` if you can do *exactly* the same with *one* command?

      ```
      find -maxdepth 100 -type d
      ```
   2. Which makes the arbitrary depth limit unnecessary

      ```
      find -type d
      ```
   3. Don't *ever* parse the output of `ls`, *especially* if you can let `find` handle that, too

      ```
      find -not -type d
      ```
   4. Make sure it works in the worst possible case:

      ```
      find -not -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' FILENAME; do
      ```

      This stops `read` from eating certain escapes and choking on filenames with new-line characters.
2. You are repeating the *entire* `ls | replace` cycle for *every single character*. **Don't** - it kills performance. Loop over <s>each directory</s> all files *once*, and just use multiple `sed`'s, or multiple replacements in one `sed` command.

   ```
   sed 's/á/a/g; s/í/i/g; ...'
   ```

   (I was going to suggest `sed 'y/áí/ai/'`, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work with Unicode. Perhaps `perl -CS -Mutf8 -pe 'y/áí/ai/'` would.)
3. You're still thinking in ASCII: *"other special chars - ASCII Codes 33.. ..255"*. Don't.

   1. These days, most systems use Unicode in UTF-8 encoding, which has a *much* wider range of "special" characters - so big that listing them out one by one becomes pointless. (It is even *multibyte* - "e" is one byte, "ė" is three bytes.)
   2. True ASCII has 128 characters. What you currently have in mind are the ISO 8859 character sets (sometimes called "ANSI") - in particular, ISO 8859-1. But they go all the way up to 8859-16, and only the "ASCII" part stays the same.
4. `echo -n $(command)` is rather useless.
5. There are much easier ways to find the directory and basename given a path. For example, you can do

   ```
   directory=$(dirname "$path")
   oldnname=$(basename "$path")
   # filter $oldname
   mv "$path" "$directory/$newname"
   ```
6. Do *not* use `egrep` to check for errors. Check the program's return code. (Like you already do with `cd`.)
7. And instead of filtering out other errors, do...

   ```
   if [[ -e $directory/$newname ]]; then
       echo "target already exists, skipping: $oldname -> $newname"
       continue
   else
       mv "$path" "$directory/$newname"
   fi
   ```
8. The ton of `sed 's/------------/-/g'` calls can be changed to a single regexp:

   ```
   sed -r 's/-{2,}/-/g'
   ```
9. The `[ ]`s in `tr [foo] [bar]` are unnecessary. They just cause `tr` to replace `[` to `[`, and `]` to `]`.
10. Seriously?

    ```
    echo "$FOLDERNAME" | sed "s/$/\//g"
    ```

    How about this instead?

    ```
    echo "$FOLDERNAME/"
    ```

---

And finally, use [**`detox`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/detox).

Comment: +10 just for tackling that mess. +10 for detox. Unfortunately, `tr` doesn't handle Unicode either. While `grep` understands equivalence classes (`[[=a=]]` matches 'aàâãäå'), neither `sed`, `tr` or `gawk` appear to.

Comment: @Dennis: GNU `sed` supports `[[=a=]]`.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like:

```
find . -print0 -type f | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\x00"} { printf "%s\x00", $0; gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "-"); printf "%s\0", $0 }' | xargs -0 -L 2 mv
```

Use of xargs(1) will ensure that each filename passed exactly as one parameter. awk(1) is used to add new filename right after old one.

One more trick: sed -e 's/-+/-/g' will replace groups of more than one "-" with exactly one.

Comment: Okay, that's a sexy use of awk and xargs.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the rest of your script is right, your problem is that you are using `read` but you should use `read -r`.  Notice how the backslash disappeared:

```
áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&'()*+,:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£.txt
áíüűúöőóéÁÍÜŰÚÖŐÓÉ!"#$%&\'()*+,:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...

Some tips to clean up your script:

** Use sed to do translation on multiple characters at once, that'll clean things up and make it easier to manage:

```
dev:~$ echo 'áàaieeé!.txt' | sed -e 's/[áàã]/a/g; s/[éè]/e/g'
aaaieee!.txt
```

** rather than renaming the file for *each* change, run all your filters then do one move

```
$ NEWNAME='áàaieeé!.txt'
$ NEWNAME="$(echo "$NEWNAME" | sed -e 's/[áàã]/a/g; s/[éè]/e/g')"
$ NEWNAME="$(echo "$NEWNAME" | sed -e 's/aa*/a/g')"
$ echo $NEWNAME
aieee!.txt
```

** rather than doing a `ls | read ...` loop, use:

```
for OLDNAME in $DIR/*; do
  blah
  blah
  blah
done
```

** separate out your path traversal and renaming logic into two scripts. One script finds the files which need to be renamed, one script handles the normalization of a single file. Once you learn the 'find' command, you'll realize you can toss the first script :)

Comment: Perhaps you meant "for OLDNAME in "$DIR"/*

Comment: @marco: call it pseudocode :) Actually I deleted it trying to remember how to work around the code-block-in-list markdown bug.